# How can I make my jQuery plugin respect end()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

With most jQuery function calls that change the selection, it is possible to go back a step in the selection using [`end`](http://api.jquery.com/end/).  For example:

```
$('#myElement').parent().show().end().css('color', '#ff0000');
```

This shows the parent element and then makes the original selection red.

However, when I define my own jQuery plugin that filters a selection, I don't get this functionality.  For example:

```
$.fn.nextBarOne = function(selector) {
    var ret = this.next().next();

    return (typeof selector === 'undefined') ? ret : ret.filter(selector);
}
```

If I now do `$('#myElement').nextBarOne().show().end()` I don't go back to the original selection.  Obviously this is because internally the function calls `next` twice and then sometimes calls `filter`.

How can I define a jQuery plugin to allow me to use `end` like the built-in functions do?

Comment: Look in the jQuery source for "pushStack"; basically your code would call that just like the jQuery "find", "parents", etc. functions do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `prevObject` after traversing using `.next()` to point to the original jQuery object.

```
$.fn.nextBarOne = function(selector) {
    var self = this,
        ret = (typeof selector === 'undefined') ? 
                this.next().next() : this.next().next().filter(selector);
    ret.prevObject = self; 
    return ret;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Possibly cleaner with `pushStack()`. I've also included the selector in the `pushStack` call.

```
$.fn.nextBarOne = function(selector) {
    var ret = (typeof selector === 'undefined') ? 
                this.next().next() : this.next().next().filter(selector);
    return this.pushStack(ret, "nextBarOne", selector || "");           
}
```

**[An example here](http://jsfiddle.net/BYmtm/)**

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1739-Using-PushStack-In-jQuery-Plugins-To-Create-New-Collections.htm

Comment: It looks like there's a common pattern - however now that I think of it I was looking in 1.4.4, not 1.5; I doubt that stuff has changed though

Comment: @Russ That works unless you use a selector -- `filter` clearly sets `prevObject` as well. I think you'd need to put the `ret.prevObject` line after all other manipulation...

Comment: @Russ Many thanks, that works great. I can't believe how useless [the API for this is](http://api.jquery.com/pushStack/). [Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BYmtm/1/).